# Django filter drop down based on another drop down

Tags: django

All I'm trying to do filter the Sub-program dropdown based on which program is pressed. Currently, I'm using one to many relationships to save many subprograms under the program node. I thought this would handle things but it's simply returning all the subprograms regardless of which program is selected.

**views.py**

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Post
fields = fields = ['asset_name', 'road_name', 'suburb', 'lifecycle', 'program', 'subprogram', 'internal_budget', 'external_budget', 'budget_year', 'finance_description', 'project_description', 'reference_description', 'attachment']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

**models.py**

```
class Program (models.Model):
program_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)  

def __str__(self):
    return self.program_name  

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('program-create')  


 class SubProgram (models.Model):
# program = models.OneToOneField(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
subprogram_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.subprogram_name  

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('subprogram-create')  

class Post (models.Model):
asset_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
road_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
suburb = models.CharField(max_length=150)
lifecycle = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CYCLE_CHOICES)
program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
subprogram = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SUBPROGRAM_CHOICES)
internal_budget = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
external_budget = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
budget_year = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=BUDGET_YEAR_CHOICES)
budget = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
finance_description = models.TextField()
project_description = models.TextField()
reference_description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
attachment = models.FileField(blank=True)
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.asset_name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.budget:
        self.budget = self.internal_budget + self.external_budget
    return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What dropdowns are you refering to? If you have made some dropdowns in a template file, then please share the template code.

Comment: @Azer I'm new to Django but I have dropdowns and I created them using these to lines of code within the `post` model, `program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` currently I don't know what to put inside of the subprogram line to make it show the correct subprograms so I just put some dummy data

Comment: `subprogram = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SUBPROGRAM_CHOICES)` I can't find where you set the value of this variable `SUBPROGRAM_CHOICES`. Could you show me the code that sets the value?

Comment: you can use ajax for this type of filter